# Insert or Update or Delete UserTerritory Using apex DML

Tags: community

How can I do DML operations on UserTerritory Object. I tried to delete but I got error "DML not allowed on UserTerritory". Do we have any work-around solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be done. See documentation on [sObjects That Don’t Support DML Operations](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm).

If you look at [this post](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000KGahAAG) on the Ideas Exchange, it looks like other APIs can accomplish what you need. OP throws [BeatBox](http://www.pocketsoap.com/beatbox/) out there, but I have not worked with it personally.

Comment: Is there a work around solution to this ? Any API.  Please share sample code

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution to this as follows:

1. Use the SFDC REST API from Apex to perform the allowed DML operations on `UserTerritory` : Create and Delete. In effect, your SFDC org does a REST call on itself.
2. To update a `UserTerritory`, you need to delete, then insert - as no update CRUD operation per:

> Supported Calls
>   create(), delete(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve()

This approach is the general solution where the SFDC API offers CRUD operations but APEX DML is limited as per Adrian's answer above